# Login Security Setting Up A Ceasar Cipher Captcha for SSH

Tags: ssh, security, login

I want to setup a captcha on ssh login that is a ceasar cipher that I come up with myself. I know there is pam-captcha and google authenticator for ssh login, but how would I setup something like a captcha on login, but requires the user to know my ceasar cipher in order to login.

The current captcha only prevents someone from brute forcing a ssh login. And the Google authenticator requires an extra device. This is why I was wonder how something like this can be done.

Comment: You can implement your own PAM module to use. But it is nothing somebody will do for you here.

Comment: @Jakuje That depends ... how much do you want to bet? ;)

Comment: bottle of beer?